# Show that a sequence of functions is uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f,f_1,f_2,\cdots$ be continuous real-valued functions on a compact metric space $E$, with $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n=f$. Show that if $f_1(p)\le f_2(p)\le \cdots$ for all $p \in E$, then the sequence $f_1, f_2, \cdots$ is uniformly convergent.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. I want to show that there exists an $N$ such that for all $n \ge N$, $\sup(|f_n-f|)<\varepsilon.$ for all $x \in E.$ Equivalently, we want to show $(f_n-f)\to 0$. I let $g_n=f_n-f$ and notice that $||g_1||\ge ||g_2|| \ge \cdots$. The image $f(E)$ is also compact and attains a maximum.

I'm not too sure where to proceed here. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

Comment: See Dini's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini's_theorem

Comment: The hypothesis should read $\lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x)=f(x)$ for each $x\in E.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the additional condition that $f$ is continuous.

Hint:  Consider $G_n = \{x: f(x) -f_n(x) < \epsilon\}$. Show by compactness and the other hypotheses that 
$$E \subset \cup_{n=1}^\infty G_n \implies E\subset \cup_{k=1}^m G_{n_k} $$

and $f(x) - f_n(x) < \epsilon$ if   $n > N = \max(n_1, \ldots n_m)$.

Comment: When you write the infinite union of all $G_n$ are we referring to the images of these functions?

Comment: I mean that $E$ is contained in (and actually equal to) the union of the sets $G_n.$

Comment: Given $\epsilon >0$, every point in $E$ must belong to at least one of the sets $G_n$ because of pointwise convergence on $E$. For any $x \in E$ there is some integer $n$ such that $f(x) - f_n(x) < \epsilon$.

Comment: Since $f - f_n$ is continuous you can show that $G_n$ is open and then proceed with the covering argument, etc.

Comment: I understand now, thanks.

Comment: Great.  You're welcome.